# JQuery Modal popup change page background color

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the page background color when the popup is activated than change page back to its original color when the modal closes. The first part works fine. The page changes color when the modal popup open but when the user clicks on the close button, the page color stays in its current state.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://localhost:60980/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost:60980/themes/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="http://localhost:60980/themes/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#menuclick").hover(function () {
                    $("#side-content").dialog({
                        width: 600,
                        height: 400,
                        title: "Quick Links Menu",
                        modal: true,
                        open: function (event, ui) {
                            $('body').css('background','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)');
                            jQuery('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
                        },
                        buttons: {
                            "Close": function () {
                                $('body').css('background','rgba(0, 0, 255)');
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menuclick">hover me
     <div id="side-content">      
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Setting `modal` to `true` will do this for you by default - assuming you've included the jQueryUI stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript works fine with this HTML :

```
<div id="menuclick">hover me
     <div id="side-content">      
     </div>
</div>
```

so maybe it is related to your HTML.

see http://jsfiddle.net/9qkxj5mr/2/

Comment: The fiddle works but the code on my end does not. I updated the question with the whole page of code.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out the issue. Kamui's fiddle works I could not get the script to work on my end. I changed background to background-color and the scripts works fine.